# Factor out a relationship between model classes as a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In my model *judges* are related to *projects* thus:

```ruby
class Judge < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  # ...
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :judges
  # ...
end
```

which is represented in SQL as

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.judges_projects (
    judge_id bigint NOT NULL,
    project_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Now I need to be able to add judge's feedback on the projects that they judge. I have written a simple migration (`add_column :judges_projects, :feedback, :string, default: ''`) which produces this revised SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.judges_projects (
    judge_id bigint NOT NULL,
    project_id bigint NOT NULL,
    feedback character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying
);
```

How do I refactor the models to include the additional field without breaking existing *judges* and *projects*?

Comment: The existing join records will get the default value in the new field -- what are you worried will break? You haven't changed anything about the judge or project models.

Comment: It should work fine. Did something break?

Answer (score 1):

It won't break Judges nor Projects. And you can use it just fine.

However, if you want to get at `feedback` you'll need to make a model for `judges_projects` now that it is not a simple join table.

```
class Judge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :judges_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :judges_projects
  # ...
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :judges_projects
  has_many :judges, through :judges_projects
end

# You might want to rename the table to something more
# descriptive.
class JudgesProject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :judge
  belongs_to :project
end
```

And you can ask for `judge.judges_projects.first.feedback`.